# HTTP POST using jQuery to get a value

Tags: jquery, http-post

I have used the below code to get a value, but it is not working. The post method returns the correct value, but I want to assign the value to a variable, but it is not working. How can I fix?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sessionID = GetSessionIDFromDB();
    alert(sessionID);
});

function GetSessionIDFromDB() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myurl + "GetSessionID",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var returnValue = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            return returnValue;
        }
    });
}
```

The `returnValue` in GetSessionIDFromDB is what I expect, but when assigned to a variable, it is null.

Comment: The `return returnValue` statement is in your `success` callback function and that is executing after the HTTP post has completed successfully. Please read [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) and also read on how JavaScript callbacks work in general

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically returned a JSON string in data.d, data.d might already be a JavaScript object, in which case you can just use:

```
var returnValue = data.d;
return returnValue;
```

Or simply:

```
return data.d;
```

Comment: That does not answer the question why the assigned variable (`sessionID`) has a null value.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. In some earlier versions of JQuery, the [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) implementation returns null if you pass it an object ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y8nbbk5/))

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now. Yes I'm wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your alert is failing is because your `GetSessionIDFromDB` function does not return any value. It only calls the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and registers the anonymous function that includes the `return returnValue` statement as a callback.

As I mentioned on the comment to your question, please read more on the concepts of JavaScript callbacks - [this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) is a good article that I could quickly google.

To make your code work, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  GetSessionIDFromDB();
});

function GetSessionIDFromDB() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myurl + "GetSessionID",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var returnValue = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            var sessionID = returnValue;
            alert(sessionID);
        }
    });
}
```